# How to make the statement "If A or B then C" More Rigorous?

Tags: logic, propositions

Suppose that I say the following,

> If A or B then C

It is clear what happens if only A is true, if only B is true, or if neither A nor B are true.

However, what happens if **both A & B are true**? I could see three possible outcomes:

- C happens (inclusive or)
- C doesn't happen (exclusive or)
- C happens twice

How can I rephrase my original statement to make the distinction explicit?

Comment: This seems to me more of an English question. Anyway, how about: If A or B, or both, then C. If A or B, but not both, then C. If A then C, and if B then C.

Comment: By default, "or" is inclusive, unless the context rules out inclusion. "And/or" is used to emphasize inclusive or, and "either or" exclusive or, that C happens twice or ten times is irrelevant to the meaning of "or". But this is not a philosophy question.

Comment: In logic, inclusive OR is the default. XOR means exclusive OR.

Comment: I wouldn't assume (A and B) unless it was written into the statement: **If (A or B) or (A and B) then C**. I don't think it's good form to assume anything not stated. A or B means just that; it shouldn't be taken to mean (A and B) if (A and B) wasn't explicitly included in the statement.

Comment: You need to understand brackets or parentheses when you have three or more variables. Surely (A v B) --> C is distinct from A v (B --> C). Which do you mean? Could you mean something else? If so then you need to be more specific and pinpoint what you want to eliminate from happening in your context.  I don't see why you would count C happening more than once.  Could you explain?

Answer (score 1):

You could rewrite "A or B" as "(A and not B) or (not A and B) or (A and B)".

You can see that these statements are equivalent using a truth table generator. Using the input 
"((A&&~B)or(~A&&B)or(A&&B))<=>(A or B)" in [this generator](http://web.stanford.edu/class/cs103/tools/truth-table-tool/) I find that all valuations of "A" and "B" give "T" values.

You could then decide with a separate if-statement what to do with the case "A and B". In other words:

> If (A and not B) or (not A and B) then C.

Now handle the case "A and B". Assume D will happen.

> If A and B then D.

There is another case to perhaps consider: "not A and not B". This could be handled by adding another if-statement.

Comment: This doesn't eliminate the ambiguity. There's still "or" in the new statement...

Comment: @Eliran It rewrites the problem in terms of four cases using conjunctions rather than relying on a definition of the disjunction of A or B. Consider each case separately using an if-statement. That should eliminate any ambiguity.

Comment: @Eliran What remains are four cases to consider. These cases cover all possibilities in a bivalent logic for two basic propositions A and B. Each case can be used as the antecedent of a conditional to rephrase the problem rather than one conditional with a disjunction as its antecedent. .The OP wants to know how to rephrase the original statement to avoid ambiguity. This would do it.